# How to get inner href inside a tag?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

The whole element is like below :

```
<h2 class="font120 mt0 mb10 mobfont110 lineheight20 moblineheight15"><a href="https://demosite.com">demo text</a></h2>
```

I have run this below command :

```
const y = document.getElementsByClassName("font120 mt0 mb10 mobfont110 lineheight20 moblineheight15")[0].innerHTML;
console.log(y);
```

And got the below result from it.

```
<a href="https://demosite.com">demo text</a>
```

Now I want to get href URL link, and then click on it. How can I do it using JavaScript?
Also In addition to that, I want to add if else statement after this which will check if href URL changes in every 5 minutes , if it changes then it should click on href URL link otherwise it should just refresh the page.

Comment: Clicking on a link changes to that page, so the current script stops. So you can't run this every 5 minutes -- once it clicks on the link, it's not running any more.

Comment: Are you allowed to add additional classes to the container? `querySelector` would be easier to manage. And are you talking about the href changing or the actual URL in the address bar?

Comment: Can we do like this ? The script will store the current url first into some variable, which can be called every 5 minutes to compare with the new url ?

Comment: Also do not use a long set of classNames to get an element. IF you need all of them it is safer to use querySelector, also you can just add the a to it: `const y = document.querySelector(".font120.mt0.mb10.mobfont110.lineheight20.moblineheight15 a").href;`

Comment: This is called an X/Y problem. Please tell us what you want to ACHIEVE instead of how you already think you could do it.

Comment: yes. I can use this below command which is giving me the same result. @mplungjan

`let y = document.querySelectorAll("h2")[0].innerHTML;
console.log(y);`

Comment: That is the same as `let y = document.querySelector("h2").innerHTML;` but do you have a link in the H2? Then `let y = document.querySelector("h2 a").href;` will work

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan  I got the URL now. Now how can I do those further addition ?

Comment: Never use selectors like `"font120 mt0 mb10 mobfont110 lineheight20 moblineheight15"` . All it takes is for you to remove one of them and see your JS fail on you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this comes close to what you want. I've tested it locally and works.

1. There are a series of anchors inside containers. Each anchor has a click event attached to it.
2. The initial href value is set to the first anchor's href attribute.
3. The code then watches for any new clicks on the anchors. If there is one a timer starts. If the new href is the same the saved one after five seconds the page reloads. If it's not the same the *new* page is loaded.
4. On each new click the timer resets.

```js
// Pick up the anchors with `querySelectorAll`
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.demo a');

// Assign a handler to them for when the click
// event is triggered. (Note `handleClick` returns
// a new function that is actually assigned to the
// listener because I wanted to use prevent any unnecessary
// global variables, and you can do that with closure
anchors.forEach(anchor => {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', handleClick());
});

function handleClick() {
  
  // Initialise the current href, and
  // the timer
  let current = anchors[0].href;
  let timer;
  
  // Return the function the listener will
  // be using
  return function (e) {
    
    // Stop the anchor from doing anything
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Get the new href from the clicked element
    const { href } = e.target;
    
    // Clear any timers
    clearTimeout(timer);
    
    // And set a new timer. If the current
    // href doesn't match the one on the clicked
    // element assign the page to a new location,
    // otherwise reload the current page.
    // This time is set for five seconds for testing
    // but you change that to five minutes (60000 x 5)
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (current !== href) {
        // location.assign(href);
        console.log(`Redirecting to ${href}`);
      } else {
        // location.reload();
        console.log(`Refreshing ${current}`);
      }
      current = href;
    }, 5000);
  
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <a href="https://demosite1.com">demo text 1</a>
</div>
<div class="demo">
  <a href="https://demosite2.com">demo text 2</a>
</div>
<div class="demo">
  <a href="https://demosite3.com">demo text 3</a>
</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

Comment: Sir what `'.demo a'` does in the first line? and keep in mind that demo text is always changing along with the new URL.

Comment: It's just a CSS selector that `querySelector` uses. It says find me all the anchors that are children of elements with the demo class. @RachelJackson. I only used because it's neater than trying to target all those classes with `getElementsyClassName` :) And note this is only a simplified example that you can use. Your question was a little vague on details.

Comment: I've added a summary, and some additional documentation. Hope that helps @RachelJackson

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is look for the `a` element using the CSS selector `h2 a` and then get its `href` attribute:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("h2 a").href)
```

```html
<h2 class="font120 mt0 mb10 mobfont110 lineheight20 moblineheight15"><a href="https://demosite.com">demo text</a></h2>
```

In order to set up a reload of the page you could set up a

```
setTimeout("location.reload()",5*60*1000)
```

This will reload the current page after five minutes and will continue to do so, as the reloaded page will contain the same (unfired) `setTimeout` function.

In order to check, whether the `href` value has changed from one to the next reloaded version you would need to store the value in `localstorage` and compare it every time after the page loads with the current `href` value.

Comment: This will return all <a> tag who is inside h2 tag. so its not 100% correct.

Comment: Well, yes, you would need to make it more specific if there are many other elements of the same structure on the page, otherwise you will just be given *the first* instance (but never *all* instances).